# Logging IP address for uniqueness without storing the IP address itself for privacy

Tags: perl, hash, ip-address, md5, privacy

In a web application when logging some data I'd like to make sure I can identify data that came at differetn times but from the same IP address. On the other hand for privacy concerns as the data will be released publicly I'd like to make sure the actual IP cannot be retrieved. So I need some one way mapping of the IP addresses to some other strings that ensures 1-1 mapping.

If I understand correctly then MD5, SHA1 or SHA256  could be a solution. I wonder if they are not too expensive in terms of processing needed?

I'd be interested in any solution though if there is implementation in Perl that would be even better.

Answer (score 6):

I'd think MD5 would be good and fast enough.  You'd want to add a few constant characters of salt to avoid rainbow table/web lookups.  For instance, the string "127.0.0.1" has md5 f528764d624db129b32c21fbca0cb8d6, which has quite a few google hits.  "szabgab127.0.0.1", on the other hand, gets "Your search - 501ff2fbdca6ee72247f8c61851f17b9 - did not match any documents" (until I post this answer...)

Comment: I didn't see anything worthy of a downvote so I upvoted to cancel.

Comment: I'd assume it's the anti-MD5 forces at work.  For this particular purpose, I think MD5 is ok (see my comment to daxim's answer), but in general it should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Rabin fingerprinting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin_fingerprint). It is fast and easy to implement.

> Given an n-bit message m<sub>0</sub>,...,m<sub>n-1</sub>, we
>   view it as a polynomial of degree n-1
>   over the finite field GF(2).
>
> We then pick a random irreducible
>   polynomial p(x) of degree k over
>   GF(2), and we define the fingerprint
>   of m to be the remainder r(x) after
>   division of f(x) by p(x) over GF(2)
>   which can be viewed as a polynomial of
>   degree k-1 or as a k-bit number.

Note that this is still not a [perfect hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) as you seek, but to get one you're likely going to face issues being able to crack the function and obtain the original IP from the hash. In most cases, the extremely low chance of collision in fingerprinting is acceptable.

Also note that whatever hash function you end up using, it will be trivial to find which log entries are from a given IP address if your hash function is known. If you want to secure yourself against this, you should encrypt the hash.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the answers of @marcog and @daxim you could use an HMAC, for example [HMAC-SHA](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4634), with a hard-coded secret key on the log generation device. If the secret leaks out, then the scheme is becomes about as weak as any of the ones given here so far.

Or, perhaps more simply, you can just use the same secret key concept to encrypt the IP address. AES's 128 bit block size is perfect for ensuring 1-1 mappings of all possible IP addresses. Just use AES in ECB mode.

Answer (score 1):

If you just use hashes, then someone can do a brute force attack.

The easiest thing to do is to use a Bloom Filter. In particular, the C++ Bloom filter implementation at http://www.afflib.org/ allows you to add arbitrary strings to the Bloom filter and then probe to see if they are present or not. If you want to protect against a brute force attack just raise your false positive frequency so it is 1 in a billion. Then you'll have uniqueness but people won't be able to figure out which IP addresses you have seen.

Answer (score 0):

⚠ Do not use [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) or [SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) any more. ⚠ See the articles for their weaknesses.

Use salted [SHA-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) instead, [Crypt::SaltedHash](http://p3rl.org/Crypt%3a%3aSaltedHash) provides a nice abstraction. The recommended Perl binding is [Digest::SHA](http://p3rl.org/Digest%3a%3aSHA) and uses XS.

You talk about expensive. Have you profiled the code yet? Code not yet written? Then it's way [too early to think about optimisation](http://xoa.petdance.com/Rules_of_Optimization_Club). Security must be the first concern.

---

Edit: example code

```
use Crypt::SaltedHash;
my $normalised_string_representation_of_internet_address = '::1';    # or perhaps '10.10.10.10'

# when you first get an address, make a hash and store it
my $csh = Crypt::SaltedHash->new(algorithm => 'SHA-512', salt_len => 32);
$csh->add($normalised_string_representation_of_internet_address);
my $salted = $csh->generate;

# later retrieve the hash and see whether it matches
my $valid = Crypt::SaltedHash->validate($salted, $normalised_string_representation_of_internet_address, 32);
```

Comment: If you use a salt, then the same IP address will map to different hashes at different time. This will defeat one of the purposes of the log.

Comment: The salt is of course stored together with the hash, your concern is moot. This should be abundantly clear if you have ever done this before. - I add some code that demonstrates that this works.

Comment: No, this makes sense for passwords but not for this app. There will be no chance to "validate" the IP address after the hashed address is logged.

Comment: To detect duplicate IPs, you can only use a constant salt.  Storing a random salt with the hash is of no use.  And the weaknesses of MD5 really don't apply to such short pieces of data.  In any case, whatever algorithm is used, if the hashing method is known by the attacker, a brute force attack starting with likely IP address ranges is going to have some success.  (Well, random salts do make that much much harder, but again, random salts are not suitable for this purpose.)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [Crypt::Eksblowfish::Bcrypt](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Crypt%3a%3aEksblowfish%3a%3aBcrypt). The reason it's "better" however is precisely because it is (eks)pensive—how expensive is tunable—which makes cracking attempts anywhere from somewhat to ludicrously impractical. For your application you could cache the crypted IPs so it wouldn't be slow when duplicates were seen at least.